# Smartgwt - create a panel with title and a border

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

This sounds like a pretty simple thing to do but I havent been able to find an easy way to do this. How do I create a panel with a title and a border which can contain my widgets? I have seen the SectionStack class which provides this. But I dont want to create a section stack.

Window can be added to a layout and drawn. But is it the only way or is there a container class that I am missing?

Also, how does one center things? Say a textfield and a button at the center of the page. How is this achieved?

Comment: *bump* ... hoping it works the same way that it does in forums!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a DynamicForm, you can give it a border and title with

```
form.setIsGroup(true);
form.setGroupTitle(title);
```

This actually works for Canvas, too (which is the superclass of most widgets and layouts in SmartGWT).

(I just had the same problem, and found this question, as well as the thread [Is there a "titled Border"](http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?p=57340) on the SmartGWT Forums, which gave this answer. I tried and it seems to work.)

Answer (score 0):

To do form-related tasks, look into [`DynamicForm`](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/DynamicForm.html). To set the inputs in the form, you use `setItems(Item...)`. A text field is a `TextItem`. You set it's `title` to control the label that SmartGWT will build. To get a title for the form, the best I've come up with is to use a container canvas that will contain both the title (probably a `Label` element) and the `DynamicForm`. To center the inputs, I believe you'd need to use `setAlignment` on the `DynamicForm`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I ended up doing what you have suggested but not quite satisfied with the outcome. This is a very basic task and if you see the other available frameworks, they make this very easy. Shouldn't be so hard or time consuming in a framework that is great otherwise!

Answer (score 0):

You could create an object that is actually a VLayout  that contains a Label (the tile), has a border as you need and includes a Canvas (the generic stuff you want included).

In my experience, I noticed that very often I have a DynamicForm visible, so I just add a BlurbItem control to diplay the tile and a small explanation.

Comment: Thanks. See my comment to Hank Gay's response above.